# delete rows following a given pattern

Tags: excel, csv, ms-office

There is an Excel file, which has values in even number rows, while the odd number rows are all empty. I would like to delete all those rows that do not have values, i.e., odd number rows. How to do that in Excel? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Select columns A & B and sort on column A will produce the result you want in this case.

Comment: Hi eshwar, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    For i = N To 1 Step -2
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```